# Doing a proper query with JOIN

Tags: sql

I'm really not sure how to query this at all. I have in my DB the following

id,employee,jobsite1,stime,etime,lunchout,lunchin,description,materials,jobsite2,stime,etime,lunchout2,lunchin2,description2,materials2

That actually repeats 5 times. When I do SELECT * from table works like a charm pulls all my data (I export this into an xls to edit it), I then take all the info from jobsite2,3,4,&5 and copy and paste it onto ONE row. so basically

```
ID, EMPLOYEE, JOBSITE,  , STIME,ETIME,LUNCHOUT,LUNCHIN, DESCRIPTION, MATERIALS
1,  CHRIS   , MYSITE,   , 9:00, 1:00 ,12:15,   12:45  , WORKED HERE, NONE
1,  CHRIS   , SECONDSITE, 1:15, 5:00 ,        ,       , WORKED HERE, NONE
2,  BOB     , MYSITE    , 9:00, 5:00 ,12:00   ,12:30  , WORKED HERE, NONE
3,  MIKE    , MYSITE    , 9:00, 2:00 ,12:00   ,12:30  , WORKED HERE, BOUGHT STUFF
3,  MIKE    , SECONDSITE, 2:00, 5:30 ,        ,       , DOING THIS , NONE
```

IS there a way to query this without me doing this manually through excel? Using maybe JOIN? I have never used JOIN, but heard about it, and was always curious is exporting this could be easier once I have the right query setup? Does this make sense?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Please specify your database and version, provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: It all submits into a single table. DB name is employee table name is tcardsubmit so...employee.tcardsubmit
Not sure what MySQL version number is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,you can do it using `UNION`

```
SELECT  id, employee, jobsite1, stime1, etime1, 
        lunchout1, lunchin1, description1, materials1
FROM tableName
UNION
SELECT  id, employee, jobsite2, stime2, etime2, 
        lunchout2, lunchin2, description2, materials2
FROM tableName
UNION
SELECT  id, employee, jobsite3, stime3, etime3, 
        lunchout3, lunchin3, description3, materials3
FROM tableName
UNION
SELECT  id, employee, jobsite4, stime4, etime4, 
        lunchout4, lunchin4, description4, materials4
FROM tableName
SELECT  id, employee, jobsite5, stime5, etime5, 
        lunchout5, lunchin5, description5, materials5
FROM tableName
```

Comment: This is definitely the right approach.  Two things to keep in mind.  (1) You might want to filter to remove blank rows (something like "where jobsite<n> is not null").  Also, this removes duplicates between numbers, which may or may not be desirable.  Another column, giving the number, would fix this.

Comment: Thank you so much that seemed to do the trick! Would the filter have to be put on every row? jobsite2,starttime2,endttime2 ect? Either way it's perfect for what I need.